# Rest Service on top of Presto

Tags: rest, presto

Is it possible to build a Rest Service on top of presto to do distributed query. Can anyone help me with a link regarding the same. I found out that qubole can submit a Presto command from the command line, but it doesn't answer my question as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Presto REST API is documented here: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/wiki/HTTP-Protocol

Additionally, there are Presto clients for most popular programming languages: https://prestosql.io/resources.html